# How to console server response in angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image-uploading

I am using this library to upload image [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

Every thing is working fine except I am not getting response back from server,As I am sending json data from server and I want to use that data in front end ..How can I achieve this?

This is what I am using as callback:

```
uploader.bind('progress', function (event, item, progress) {
        console.log('Progress: '+item);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

angular-file-upload does support this event:

`onProgressItem function(item, progress) {: On file upload progress.`

as can be seen [here](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API#directives)

so then you will most likely have:

```
uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
    console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
};
uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
    console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
};
```

example found [here](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/examples/simple/controllers.js)

Comment: When I console "fileItem" , I can see my response. But how can I get that response as it is inside " fileItem._xhr.response " and not working for me

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, your question is very vague

Comment: To do what? Get the progress so you can update a %? Fire a success function after the upload finished?

I also do not know what you are actually getting back, so that and your vague question is making it extremely difficult to help you